# Why are all paragraphs in my document not indented?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I am working on a document in Overleaf and all paragraphs are not indented.
I cannot see what is forcing this behaviour, since Latex default is indenting paragraphs after the first one in each section.
Here is my preamble:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
%\documentclass[
%]{book}
\documentclass[a5paper,pagesize,10pt,bibtotoc,pointlessnumbers,    
normalheadings,DIV=9,twoside=false]{scrbook}    
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{trajan}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
   \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
   \setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1
  \let\oldpar\par
  \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\oldpar}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
 \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {} 

\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
```

Comment: Your example is incomplete so others cannot copy and test your code.

Comment: Did you leave a `\tightlist` somewhere you shouldn't?

Comment: you are loading the parskip package or use the KOMA parskip option.

Comment: \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}  sets indent to zero

Comment: Thanks, Ulricke Fischer! Turning off Koma Parskip option did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
   \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
   \setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
```

*You* are telling LaTeX that you want nonzero parskip and no indentation, because you're telling that if the class is one of the KOMA suite, the option `parskip=half` has to be honored.

But I see at the end that the preamble is generated by `pandoc`. *Never* use such a preamble in a standalone LaTeX document. The program `pandoc` is supposed to work with older TeX distributions, so the generated preamble is full of “fallbacks”.

The code has also oldstyle KOMA options and issues very annoying warnings.

Here's a cleaned up version.

```
\documentclass[
  a5paper,
  pagesize,
  10pt,
  bibliography=totoc,% <-- changed
  numbers=noenddot, % <-- changed
  headings=normal, % <-- changed
  %DIV=9,
  twoside=false,
  %parskip=half,
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{trajan}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}

\ifPDFTeX
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  %\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts

\usepackage{xcolor}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{selnolig}  % disable illegal ligatures
\fi

\usepackage[hyphens]{xurl}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{
  hidelinks,
}


\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
}
%\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\newlength{\cslhangindent}
\setlength{\cslhangindent}{1.5em}
\newlength{\csllabelwidth}
\setlength{\csllabelwidth}{3em}
\newlength{\cslentryspacingunit} % times entry-spacing
\setlength{\cslentryspacingunit}{\parskip}
\newenvironment{CSLReferences}[2] % #1 hanging-ident, #2 entry spacing
 {% don't indent paragraphs
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  % turn on hanging indent if param 1 is 1
  \ifodd #1\relax
    \def\par{\hangindent=\cslhangindent\endgraf}
  \fi
  % set entry spacing
 \setlength{\parskip}{#2\cslentryspacingunit}
 }%
 {} 


\newcommand{\CSLBlock}[1]{#1\hfill\break}
\newcommand{\CSLLeftMargin}[1]{\parbox[t]{\csllabelwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\CSLRightInline}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linewidth - \csllabelwidth}{#1}\break}
\newcommand{\CSLIndent}[1]{\hspace{\cslhangindent}#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just to fill pages

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

You see that by commenting out the `parskip=half` option, paragraphs are indeed indented.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot!